# How to fix FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:? (HEROKU)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, dj-rest-auth

I am trying to push my Django + React app to heroku. I have configured the path for my static files at below in settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'laundryman_frontend/build/static')
]
```

The build is successful when I push to heroku but when I run `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic` I get the error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/laundryman_frontend/build/static'`

this is what BASE_DIR is set to:
`BASE_DIR=os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`

My guess is that, Heroku is not looking does not recognise the path that I have set for the static files.

Kindly help me solve this issue

Comment: What have you set BASE_DIR to?   Normally it would be set something like this `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))`.  Did you set it differently?   Or is `manage.py` in the root directory?

Comment: ```BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))``` I have updated the question with what BASE_DIR is set to

Comment: And what is the absolute pathname for your static directory?

Comment: ```manage.py``` is in the root directory....  absolute pathname for static directory: ```C:/Users/shaphat/Desktop/PROJECTS/START_UPS/LAUNDRYMAN/laundryman/laundryman_frontend/build```

Comment: (Yea I already figured that out ...)

Comment: I have updated the previous comment

Answer (score 0):

The logic of the code snippets in your question is very simple.

1. Set `BASE_DIR` to the directory that contains the `manage.py` file.

   ```
   BASE_DIR=os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
   ```
2. Set the `STATICFILES_DIRS` relative to the `BASE_DIR`.

   ```
   STATICFILES_DIRS = [
       os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app/laundryman_frontend/build/static')
   ]
   ```

If that "algorithm" doesn't work (i.e. your Django app's static files directory is set incorrectly) then:

- `manage.py` is in the wrong place, or
- the relative path you provided is incorrect, or (maybe)
- some stuff hasn't been deployed.

I guess it is also possible that `collectstatic` didn't work; see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

Comment: I have tried everything but it is stiil not working. Heroku keeps looking at ```"app/laundryman_frontend/build/static"``` meanwhile I have set STATICFILES_DIRS to ```os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'laundryman_frontend/build/static')```  I dont know why heroku preceedes the path with "app".